# Running a PHP webapp from Java

Tags: java, php, resin, quercus

I'm interested in running a PHP web application using [Quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin/doc/quercus.xtp) in a way similar to:

```
java -classpath ... com.example.LaunchPHP {php folder}
```

All the documentation I could find on Quercus was related to running from Resin, but this is something I want as simple as possible, for running from a CI build.

What possibilities are there?

Answer (score 1):

Would it be easier to open a URLConnection and hit the PHP page through the web server?

Comment: My setup is such that I can't guarantee access to a web server like Apache - but I can control the Java part.

Answer (score 0):

Digging through the `QuercusServlet` source, it appears that you would need to call `Quercus.parse` to get a `QuercusPage` on which you could call `execute`.  I suspect there's some more setup you'd have to do first (like initializing php.ini values), but I think reading through the `QuercusServlet` source should send you in the right direction.